# Linq where Unique

Tags: c#, linq

The Linq method `Distinct` gets one of each object in an IEnumerable.
However what if I don't want to include non distinct objects at all.
For example, given

a,
a,
b,
c,
c,
c,
d,
e

I want a Method `WhereUnique` which will return b,d,e but not a or d as both of them appear multiple times.

The obvious method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereUnique<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    return items.Where(x => items.Count(y => y == x) <= 1);
}
```

Is O(n^2), and I would hope for something more efficient than that.

Ideally it should support WhereUniqueBy(), similiar to DistinctBy().

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereUnique<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    return items.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() ==1).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

possibly slightly more performant

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereUnique<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    return items.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => !x.Skip(1).Any()).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

And WhereUniqueBy

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereUniqueBy<T, TSelector>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TSelector> func)
{
    return items.GroupBy(func).Where(x => x.Count() ==1).Select(x => x.First());
}
```